# auto Increment starts at maximum value

Tags: mysql

I set an auto increment at one of my mysql columns like this:

```
ALTER TABLE i_rapport MODIFY COLUMN rapportID INT auto_increment
```

but when i submit a form on my webpage, it sets the rapportID as 2147483647

this is my sql;

```
$sql="INSERT into int_rapport( omschr, status, prioriteit, productnr, versienr,gebruikerID, datum)
  VALUES('$omschr','$status','$prioriteit','$productnr','$versienr','$gebruikerID','$datum')";
```

do i need to put the rapportID in the sql query?

any help would be appreciated !

Comment: given that query string, you're likely vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: It's just a school assignment but.. how i would i fix that?

Comment: It's NEVER too early to learn how to write secure code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: I'll check that out, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run this script in order to set your rapportID starts at whatever value you want.

```
ALTER TABLE i_rapport AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!